# Bash script error

Tags: bash, shell-script

I created this bash script based on answers I found here:

```
If [[ $(autorep -J jobname | cut -c108-110 | sed -n '/ST/!'p | sed '/^$/d' | sed -n '/_/!'p) == *ST* ]]; then
    echo "Status is Started"
fi
```

error:

```
./stj.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

1. The command inside the `()` works if I cut and paste in the terminal, but I get an error when I execute with the `if` command.

Answer (score 4):

You indicate that you said `If`. 
bash keywords are case-sensitive; you must use `if` (lower case).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having a capital `if` as Scott pointed out, the terminal may require termination of the "then" statement (assuming you are pasting it in on one line).

Try pasting:

```
if [[ $(autorep -J jobname | cut -c108-110 | sed -n '/ST/!'p | sed '/^$/d' | sed -n '/_/!'p) == *ST* ]]; then echo "Status is Started"; fi
```

(note the semi-colon before the `fi`)

Comment: This is only true if you write it as a one-liner like you did.

Comment: Thanks yoonix I edited my answer clarifying my assumption.